# android media player error while playing : E/MediaPlayer(4768): error (1, -2147483648)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

getting error while playing sound in Android 4.0 but this code works on 2.3.3

```
                        mp = new MediaPlayer();
            mp.setDataSource(recordedSoundFilePath);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
```

**error Logs are**

```
02-21 05:42:44.542: E/MediaPlayer(4768): error (1, -2147483648)
02-21 05:42:44.550: E/MediaPlayer(4768): Error (1,-2147483648)
02-21 05:42:44.550: D/MediaPlayer(4768): Info (1,-2147483648)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: prvn, did you fix this problem ??

Answer (score -1):

```
   {final FileInputStream i = openFileInput("local file name with no /s");
    player.setDataSource(i.getFD());
    i.close();
   }
```

Comment: An explanation makes your answer more useful.